# Check if a username have permission to folder on windows

Tags: c++, windows, permissions

In my programs, i want to check whether a username have a permission to a folder on windows. But this username may not the user who current log on user.Did the windows provide the similar API?

Comment: You generally want to do it by just trying to do the access. Anything else is subject to race conditions. Use LogonUser (or LsaLogonuser) to log the user on, then ImpersonateUser to impersonate them and do the test (and RevertToSelf when you're done).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`AccessCheck()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815.aspx):

> The AccessCheck function determines whether a security descriptor grants a specified set of access rights to the client identified by an access token.

However, you need an *access token* for the desired user, such as from [`LogonUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) or similar function.  There is no API function that you can pass a username string to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jerry Coffin and Remy Lebeau. I had found the solution. Look at the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637(v=vs.85).aspx
In the example, you can get the permission of a user via only a username and the permission of a folder. And so i can check whether the username have the permission to folder.